# How to define (and plot) a non-continuous function in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Suppose we have the function `y = x^2`, we could plot this *continuous* function from x=0 to x=100 like so:

```r
library("ggplot2")
eq = function(x){x^2}
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1, 100)), aes(x=x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=eq) +
  theme_void()
```

[image: ggplot2 plot of a continuous function]

#### Question

But suppose we wish to define a **non** continuous function, such that, say, it's the same as `y=x^2` but there are no values for x between 20 and 30, and 50 and 70. How could we define it?

#### Context

I'm trying to replace the second line below (`eq = function(x){x*x}`) with whatever is necessary in order to plot noncontinuous function (i.e. keeping all other code the same).

```r
library("ggplot2")
eq = function(x){x*x} # CHANGE ONLY THIS LINE (IF POSSIBLE)
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1, 100)), aes(x=x)) + 
  stat_function(fun=eq) +
  theme_void()
```

I'll be trying to plot *many* non continuous functions on the same plot, so I suspect any hacks on the plot itself (e.g. adding elements over the top of the continuous function) would not scale well..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just replace the output of your function with NAs for values of `x` that aren't part of your domain.

```r
library(ggplot2)

eq <- function(x) {
  ans <- x * x
  ans[x >= 20 & x <= 30] <- NA
  ans[x >= 50 & x <= 70] <- NA
  ans
}

ggplot(data.frame(x = c(1, 100)), aes(x)) +
  stat_function(fun = eq) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, very clear; works perfectly. Accepting in 7 minutes.

Comment: Just an alternative way to specify the function: `replace(x * x, (x >= 20 & x <= 30) | (x >= 50 & x <= 70), NA)` (although I tend to like the current, more explicit, answer better ;). Also thanks @stevec for such a nicely presented question!